# How to parse different embedded JSON types with similar JSON container structure with GSON

Tags: java, json, data-structures, gson

I'm trying to work with data using a website API that sends everything in JSON. Their format is something like:

Type 1:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "",
    "result": 
        {
            "Date": "2017-07-07T13:02:40.123",
            "Datatype1" : "type1",
            "Data1": 1.00,
            "Datatype2" : "type2",
            "Data1": 2.00
        }
}
```

Type 1 Class def:

```
public class Type1 {

    private String date;
    private String datatype1;
    private Double data1;
    private String datatype2;
    private Double data2;

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    (rest of the getters/setters)
}

public class Type1Container {
    private String success;
    private String message;
    private Type1 result;

    (rest of the getters/setters) 

    public Type1 getResult() {
        return this.result
    }
}
```

Type 2:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "",
    "result": 
        {
            "Date": "2017-07-07T13:02:40.123",
            "RandomInt" : 1,
            "RandomBool" : true,
            "RandomDouble": 1.00,
            "RandomString" : "help"
        }
}
```

Type 2 class def:

```
public class Type2 {

    private String date;
    private int randomInt;
    private Boolean randomBool;
    private double randomDouble;
    private String randomString;

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    (rest of the getters/setters)
}

public class Type2Container {
    private String success;
    private String message;
    private Type2 result;

    (rest of the getters/setters) 

    public Type2 getResult() {
        return this.result
    }
}
```

It's not only limited to 2 data types since they have multiple types of data that is similarly packaged into JSON given a specific query. They all have a success flag, message, and the various results types. Right now I have two classes for each type of data. The class that corresponds to the "result" data structure and he container class where that class is declared as "result". But since there is a large amount of different data types, it's getting a bit cluttered. But since all the data is formatted in the same container format, I wanted to know if there was an efficient way to generalize it. Possibly by passing the class as an argument when parsing the JSON string to Java object.

I'm using GSON to unpack the string into the classes using:

```
String jsonString; //assume this is already set
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type1 data = gson.fromJSON(jsonString, Type1Container.class).getResult();
```

I'd like to instead of using specific typeContainer classes, be able to do like a Container.class where it somehow knows what the inner data type is already, but I'm not sure if that's possible. But it should be possible since I think the compiler just needs to know how much space to allocate for each object.

Also some data that I get is in the form of Lists of data types, which I assume would have to inherit from a different generic Container class that has a

```
List<RandomObjectTypeX> result;
```

instead of just the object itself. But at the end of the day I just want an efficient way to handle a bunch of data types going from JSON strings -> Java objects without having to come up with 2 names with redundant code every time I handle different data types unless I need to. I know using a dynamic language would be easier since you wouldn't need to declare anything, but I'm trying to make a native android app so I want to do this in java. Thank you for your time.

Comment: If I understand your question, what you want isn't a container, but a generic. public class <T> MyContainer { String success; String message; T result; ... }.

Comment: @Joseph Larson hope your understanding is correct. But however, while parsing string to <T>MyContainer object we need mention that generic type T. That is the actual problem for him.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Let's do this in an IDE:  public static class Foo<T> {
  String success;
  String message;
  T result;
 } -- you will need a distinct class for the various types of results.